# Where do we use the object operator "->" in PHP?

Tags: php

What are the different ways where we can use object operators `->` in PHP?

Comment: Why is this closed? People are upvoting this question 8 years later, and there are sufficient answers to the question. Clearly, it's pretty easy to see what's being asked here.

Comment: @DeltaFlyer Vote for reopening this question

Answer (score 139, accepted):

PHP has two object operators.

The first, `->`, is used when you want to call a method on an instance or access an instance property.

The second, [`::`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), is used when you want to call a [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method, access a `static` variable, or call a parent class's version of a method within a child class.

Comment: Is there a name for the "->" operator ? I guess the "::" I would just call it double colon.. but this one "->" how would I call it? property accessor operator ?

Comment: @PabloCamara The first one is called the object operator and the second the class operator. I couldn't imagine someone calling something the "double colon".

Answer (score 31):

When accessing a method or a property of an instantiated class

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$a = new SimpleClass();
echo $a->var;
$a->displayVar();
```

Comment: like object->method_name(); or object->prop_name;    it means its more like dot(.) operator to access class methods and attributes.

Comment: Similar to the . class operator in java, yes... but see the PHP class documentation for details

Answer (score 11):

Call a function:

```
$foo->bar();
```

Access a property:

```
$foo->bar = 'baz';
```

where `$foo` is an instantiated object.

Answer (score 4):

It is used when referring to the attributes of an instantiated object.
e.g:

```
class a {
    public $yourVariable = 'Hello world!';
    public function returnString() {
        return $this->yourVariable;
    }
}

$object = new a();
echo $object->returnString();
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

"->" operator is the PHP related callable content.
always use to call an instance method and access instance.

"::" scope operator is used for the instance
that is used for calling the static method and constant it's very different with::

It's a proper reply to them, I have got new knowledge.

Please check the name conflicts for the above different operator.

Answer (score -1):

arrow operator(->): It is an access operator used to access data members and methods in a class in PHP. It is the same as the (.) operator which we use in javascript, c++.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).