# What is the name of '->' in PHP?

Tags: php

Whenenever I'm discussing PHP with colleagues I don't know how to describe the little arrow symbol '->' used for accessing properties and methods in PHP. Does it have a name? Is it called arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mostly call it object access operator.

EDIT: Actually, come to think of it; I usually pronounce it as "dot", since most of us here are more familiar with the dot-notation for accessing objects properties. Since it's clearly not a dot, that's probably not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: That's actually what I've been calling it so far, because I'm more familliar with JavaScript, which uses a dot

Comment: JOKE: We should simply call it "Prince", as it seems to be an unpronounceable identifier with an undefined official name. :)

Answer (score 3):

Chaining operator, read here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: Method chaining is unrelated to the name of the operator.

Comment: So when I'm reading out A->B aloud, I should say A chaining operator B?

Comment: Yes I thought so but the other's have sources that it's called `arrow operator`, see below

Answer (score 1):

It's called the object operator (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR).

Details here: [Where do we use the object operator "->" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-we-use-object-operator-in-php)

Comment: So when I'm reading out A->B aloud, I should say A object operator B?

Answer (score 0):

It's called the **Arrow Operator**

> Although it seems to be called the Arrow Operator, I can’t find
>   reference to it other than [this page on the php.net web site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). Granted,
>   I didn’t search all that long.

[This article](http://www.danifer.com/php-arrow-operator) outlines this.

Answer (score -1):

True; it's called the arrow operator:

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php