# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Problem is in this: `echo $village_id. "-" .$wg_village;`
It returns:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /files/function_20.php on line 70

And on line 70 I posted the code that is there, function works perfectly, just returns blank page with an error.

What's wrong with that line? And how can I correct that?

**EDIT:** A `var_dump` `$village_id` and `$wg_village`:

```
string(5) "80784"
object(stdClass)#25 (35) {
  ["id"]=> string(5) "80784"
  ["name"]=> string(7) "NewName"
  ["x"]=> string(3) "-99"
  ["y"]=> string(3) "-14"
  ["kind_id"]=> string(1) "5"
  ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["rs1"]=> int(36000) ["rs2"]=> int(36000)
  ["rs3"]=> int(36000) ["rs4"]=> int(36000)
  ["workers"]=> string(2) "51"
  ["troop_keep"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["time_update_rs1"]=> string(19) "2014-05-09 01:45:30"
  ["time_update_rs2"]=> string(19) "2014-05-09 01:45:30"
  ["time_update_rs3"]=> string(19) "2014-05-09 01:45:30"
  ["time_update_rs4"]=> string(19) "2014-05-09 01:45:30"
  ["nation_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["merchant_underaway"]=> string(1) "0"
  ["child_id"]=> string(0) "" ["cp"]=> string(3) "104"
  ["cpupdate_time"]=> string(19) "2014-05-08 21:49:55"
  ["krs1"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["krs2"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["krs3"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["krs4"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["faith"]=> string(1) "3"
  ["faith_time"]=> string(19) "2014-05-07 22:05:44"
  ["dateCreate_vila"]=> string(19) "2014-05-05 20:38:26"
  ["capa123"]=> int(36000)
  ["capa4"]=> int(36000)
  ["speedIncreaseRS1"]=> float(1000)
  ["speedIncreaseRS2"]=> float(600)
  ["speedIncreaseRS3"]=> float(800)
  ["speedIncreaseRS4"]=> float(1200)
  ["speedIncreaseRS4Real"]=> float(1149)
}
```

Comment: Either `$village_id` or `$wg_village` is an object rather than a number or string, so you can't just echo it. You need to echo some property of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referencing an `object` you can't treat it as a `string`. Try dumping it out and see if you can reference a property inside

```
 var_dump($village_id);
 var_dump($wg_village);
```

So now that we have a dump, let's try to access those properties

```
 echo $village_id. "-" .$wg_village->name;
```

The only reason that should fail is if the property is `protected` or `private`, but this looks like a database result set.

You have to reference the properties using the `->` operator. You cannot call them directly. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037536/2370483) describes that in more detail.

Comment: My guess is the object is `$wg_village`.

Comment: it returns string(5) "80784"

Comment: Try the other one next

Comment: Edited post with results

Comment: Updated with your object data

Comment: Will accept that answer as soon as i can it shows me that i cant at the moments THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

First, you are trying to `echo` the contents of an object.  So first do the following to see what’s in `$village_id` as well as `$wg_village`. You just used `var_dump` but I prefer to use `print_r` with `<pre>` tags for readability:

```
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($village_id);
echo '</pre>'; 

echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($wg_village);
echo '</pre>';
```

So you can try that as well to make things clearer. But from what I am reading, it seems like `$village_id` is a string with the value of `80784` while `$wg_village` is an object. Now the thing is, what exactly do you want to get from the `$wg_village` object?

You would need to access that data like this:

```
echo $wg_village->id;
echo $wg_village->name;
echo $wg_village->x;
echo $wg_village->y;
etc…
```