# Syntax error on PHP - in need of fresh eyes

Tags: php

stupid question I know, but I need fresh eyes as I cannot see the error.

My code is this :

```
$element = $this->domDocument->getElementByTagName("Team");
        for ($i =0 ; $i < $element.length ; $i ++ ) {
        print $element[$i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
```

and the error is :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['  on line 40
```

which is the line with the print statement.

Can you spot what is wrong?

Comment: $element.length  should be $element->length

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: If you are posting about a specific error you **must** include the full error message (with line number) and at least the code on that line and the line before it.

Comment: and it is `getElement**s**ByTagName` if you want to iterate ...

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I have included everything. Line 40 is the line with the print statement, you can see the previous lines as well, and this is the full error message. Please re-read the questions. Thanks for the link, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$element = $this->domDocument->getElementsByTagName("Team");
for ($i =0 ; $i < $element->length ; $i ++ ) {
    print $element[$i]->childNodes[0]->nodeValue;
}
```

I guess you're mixing up multiple languages ;)

Comment: +1, _I guess you're mixing up multiple languages_ - probably thats why it was so hard to spot the syntax errors :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not use *dot notation* for objects, instead it uses an [object operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-we-use-object-operator-in-php) (arrow).

```
$element = $this->domDocument->getElementsByTagName("Team");
for ($i =0 ; $i < $element->length ; $i ++ ) {
    print $element[$i]->childNodes[0]->nodeValue;
}
```