# What I'm doing wrong in following array manipulation in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array, key-value

I've an array titled `$photos` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fileURL] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo
            [filename] => IMG_0004.JPG
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fileURL] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza
            [filename] => IMG_0003.JPG
        )

)
```

Now I want to create a new array titled `$values` as follows :

```
 Array
(
    [vshare] => Array
        (
            [IMG_0003.JPG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/RqAN2jZ7ScC8eOx6ckUE
                )

            [IMG_0004.JPG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XdwtFsu6RLaoZurZXPug
                )

        )

)
```

For this I tried following code :

```
$values = array();
        foreach($photos as $photo ) {
          $values['vshare'][$photo->filename] = array($photo->fileURL);
        }
```

Then I got following wrong output when I `print_r($values)`:

```
Array
(
    [vshare] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Can someone please correct the mistake I'm making in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> is operator for objects, as expleined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-we-use-object-operator-in-php).

Try:

```
$values = array();
foreach($photos as $photo ) {
    $values['vshare'][$photo['filename']] = array($photo['fileURL']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$values = array();
foreach($photos as $photo ) {
   $values['vshare'][$photo['filename']][0] = $photo['fileURL'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code

```
$values = array();
foreach($photos as $photo) {
    $values['vshare'][$photo['filename']] = array(0 => $photo['fileURL']);
}
```

Works fine for me.