# Access a specific value from Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array and I want to access a specific value without doing loop.. is it possible?

here's the array:

```
    Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [akeebasubs_user_id] => 205
        [user_id] => 268
        [isbusiness] => 0
        [businessname] => sci555
        [occupation] => 
        [vatnumber] => 
        [viesregistered] => 0
        [taxauthority] => 
        [address1] => Ma. Cristina St.
        [address2] => Negros Oriental
        [city] => Dumaguete
        [state] => IA
        [zip] => 6200
        [country] => BS
        [params] => {"work_telephone":"232424","hospital_company":"sci5","company_introductory":"test","organization_type":"","applicant_url":"www","user_title":"","year_established":"","parent_company":"","r_01":"","r_02":"","r_03":"","r_04":""}
        [notes] => <p>test</p>
    )

)
```

what I want is to access the `user_id` which is `268` directly.

Comment: why not use foreach loop & what is your stuff to achieve output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do the following:

```
var_dump($array[0]->user_id);
```

`$array`is a one-entry array that contains an `stdClass` object ([you access an object property by using `->`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-we-use-object-operator-in-php)).

Comment: You're welcome. Please also feel free to accept the answer as soon as you will be able to do so :).