# Using the object operator in PHP

Tags: php, html

I looked at this post to try and understand the object operator better: 
[Where do we use the object operator "->" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-do-we-use-the-object-operator-in-php)

But when I copied and pasted the php in the 2nd response, I just get a blank page when I run it. Here is my code:

PHP:

```
<?php

    class SimpleClass
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$a = new SimpleClass();
echo $a->var;
$a->displayVar();

?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action ="process.php" method ="POST">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> 

            <input type="submit">       
        </form>

        <p>
            Click for objectOperator.php
            <button onsubmit="objectOperator.php">Submit</button>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ignore the form in the HTML, that was for something else I was doing. When I click on the Submit button I want to run the php in objectOperator.php (which is the name of my php file). But when I click it nothing happens.

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: The `onsubmit` attribute is supposed to contain Javascript. Not the name of a file. And unless I'm mistaken, it's only valid inside a `<form>` element.

Comment: First of all you can only place a JavaScript function or code in the onsubmit event handler. Second, onsubmit is not valid for a button.

Comment: Thanks you two, I made a new form that called the php fille with action="..." and got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

I just tried this on phpfiddle and it was working

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
// property declaration
public $var = 'a default value';

// method declaration
public function displayVar() {
    echo $this->var;
}
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$a = new SimpleClass();
echo $a->var;
$a->displayVar();
}
?>


<form action ="" method ="POST">First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> 
<input type="submit">       
</form>
```

The key is to have the correct action