# what is the meaning of a symbol -> in php

Tags: php

```
<?php 

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($connect);

echo "The list of database are: <br>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) 
    {
        echo $row-> Database. "<br>";
    }

?>
```

echo $row-> Database. "
";

what this line is telling .. what does this -> mean

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-do-we-use-the-object-operator-in-php

Answer (score 1):

check out this link for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

the short of it is they are used to interact with properties and functions within an object or class.

Comment: thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

-> Symbol is used to access an object's property.
Example if i have a user object that contains the property "name", "age". To access them i can do $user->name, $user->age.

Comment: thanks alot for your help