# Why i can't insert into join view

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Studio
( name VARCHAR(30),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  pres VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
);


CREATE TABLE Movie
( title VARCHAR(50),
  year NUMERIC(4),
  length NUMERIC(3),
  inColor CHAR(1),
  studioName VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (title, year),
  FOREIGN KEY (studioName) REFERENCES Studio(name)

MariaDB [movieindustry9]> CREATE VIEW MovieStudio AS
    -> SELECT
    -> Movie.title, Movie.year, Movie.length, Movie.studioName, Studio.address, Studio.pres
    -> FROM
    -> Movie, Studio ;
    );

MariaDB [movieindustry9]> INSERT INTO
    -> MovieStudio
    -> VALUES
    -> ('Madagascar 3', 2012, 93, 'Paramount Pictures',  'Hollywood, California, USA', 'Brad Grey') ;
```

ERROR 1394 (HY000): Can not insert into join view 'movieindustry9.moviestudio' without fields list

> Any idea to fix it ? or can anyone explain why this happened ?

Comment: The error-message is very self-explanatory: **you need to list the columns you want to insert into**. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Also, while inserting into a `VIEW` is a standard feature of an RDBMS, I don't think it's a good idea to *intentionally* design an application to insert into a view because doing-so places restrictions on what the VIEW can do, for example - and it will make SQL beginners scratch their heads because it's one of the (many) unexpected and surprising things ISO SQL can do (meanwhile, we **still** can't reference columnar expressions in the same `SELECT` clause, the SQL committee's priorities are all messed-up imo).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the NUMERIC data type in MariaDB. Can you point to a document that discusses that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should read the error message, it tells you that you need the columns,
You cannot:

```
INSERT INTO
    -> MovieStudio
    -> VALUES
    -> ('Madagascar 3', 2012, 93, 'Paramount Pictures',  'Hollywood, California, USA', 'Brad Grey') ;
```

You need:

```
INSERT INTO
    -> MovieStudio(Field_name, Another_one, etc)
    -> VALUES
    -> ('Madagascar 3', 2012, 93, 'Paramount Pictures',  'Hollywood, California, USA', 'Brad Grey') ;
```

Also Personally I wouldn't insert values into a view, create a table for that, Especailly since you are a beginner, doing such things is not a good idea..... Also you are a beginner I would avoid using the

```
->
```

Syntax for now, [Where do we use the object operator "->" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-do-we-use-the-object-operator-in-php) It is a bit too complicated for you to understand right now....

Comment: There's no mention of PHP here.

Comment: @Strawberry I couldn't find what -> does in MySQL so I assumed she tried to insert PHP notations into MySQL??