# how to call a specific string from object(stdClass)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category table and a product table, i want to fetch all the category and for each category it
should display the products associated to that category , but i can't seem to put them in order

```
 $get_cat = $this->AdminModel->getcategorie();

  foreach($get_cat as $cats){

    $cats->id = $this->AdminModel->getproducts($cats->id);
     
  }

$data=['prod'=>$get_cat];
```

[image]

so the places that shows 0 and 1 should display the categories name but instead it is being displayed in the product table

if i do a `var_dump()` on `$pros` this is what i get

[image]

so how can I display categories name and the products associated with that categories

Here is the loop with the HTML tag

```
 <?php foreach($data['prod']  as $cats => $pros) :?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- SELECT2 EXAMPLE -->
    <div class="card card-default collapsed-card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $cats; ?></h3>

    <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Product Name</th>
                                            <th>Edit</th>
                                            <th>Delete</th>
               
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                             <?php $i=1;  foreach($pros as $pro): ?>
                                 <tr>
                                                        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo $pro ?></td>
                                                         
                                                        <td>Edit</td>
                                                        <td>Delete</td>
                                                    
                                         
                                        </tr>


                                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                                      
                                    
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do we use the object operator "->" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-do-we-use-the-object-operator-in-php)

Comment: @MartinZeitler if i use the -> operator it gives me a `Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in`

Comment: We have no real view of your object model. Are you using MVC methodology? Perhaps take a look here: https://krisjordan.com/blog/2008/11/27/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass

Comment: @Martin yes i am using an mvc methodology

Comment: I was able to fix it, I just used ajax to call the categories and the products

Comment: If you post the code where you are trying to loop through your categories and products and display them in the tables, that will help us show you where any mistakes are being made. The more exact details you can share, the easier it is to help.

Comment: @AkenRoberts i am sorry sir what do want me to display , do you want the loop with the HTML tags in it or the SQL query ?

Comment: The loop with HTML. Your data is being queried fine and is shown in your `var_dump`, it's just not being accessed properly.

Comment: @AkenRoberts i have edited my question